# png made in GIMP not exporting with transparency

Tags: gimp, transparency, png

I've just edited one photo in GIMP to have a transparent background.

The first photo exported fine (with the transparency), however the second photo does not export with the transparency.

I'm using GIMP 2.8.16. Screenshot below.

---

[image]

Edited to add photo: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeGdf.jpg

Comment: The usual problem is exporting to a format that doesn't support transparency, such as JPG. Use a format that does (this usually means PNG).

Comment: You need to add more info. What are you using to view it?  A browser? Other software? Can you share the actual file?  The image you posted shows transparency - so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, i did export it as a PNG. The screenshot shows what i see when i am in GIMp, however when i view a thumbnail (such as looking at the contents of a folder) it shows with the background. Also, when i uploaded to my website, it shows with the background. I'll see if i can share the actual file.

Comment: The thumbnail creator is not required to show transparency. Your website could recompress the picture to JPEG and thus lose the transparency. Re-download the file from the website and compare with your local one.

Answer (score 1):

Your link https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeGdf.jpg gives a JPG with a background. That background is not single color, See it here:

[image]

JPG cannot have transparency.Someone has converted your image to JPG. GIMP doesn't by default remove the color information from the transparent pixels when exporting as PNG. So when your PNG was converted to JPG, the original background can in theory be restored.